# Multiplicative digital root - new Input in Scanner

Tags: input, java.util.scanner, root, digital

I want to get the multiplicative digital root of a entry from a scanner. I have some issues though getting a new input, when you e.g enter a negative or a higher number than 1 million.

How can I get the input again and try to calculate again in these cases?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Calculate multiplicative digital root");

    int x = sc.nextInt();
    int mdc = 1; //multiplicative digital root = mdc
    if (x >= 0 && x <= 1000000) {
        while (x != 0) {
            mdc = mdc * (x % 10);
            x = x /10;
        }
    System.out.println(mdc);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Wrong number range or negative");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the main issue? You trying to limit the number range of the input and want to validate the input as positive?

Comment: If the else statement occurs, I want the user to make a new input with the scanner, without to run the programm again.